# Change Value with JS/Jquery Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I build a form on a Wordpress Website with a Pagebuilder Plugin. I want to change the value="submit" to something else. This is how the code looks when I look inside with Chrome Dev Tools.

```
<p class="input-submit full-size">
    <span class="input-row">
        <span class="submit-wrap">
            <input class="input-required" type="submit" name="form-submit" value="Submit">
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Sadly there is no Option inside the Pagebuilder to change it so I need Javascript I guess. Can you guys help me how to change the value? I cant select an ID, since there is none. I tried some stuff but without success -->

```
if( body.hasClass("page-id-2383") )
{
    $(".submit").val("New Value");
}
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[value=submit]").value  = "New Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use::

```
if( body.hasClass("page-id-2383") ) {
  $('input[name="form-submit"]').val("New Value");
}
```

Working link:: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt29cugo/

Answer (score 0):

Use this One

```
 $(".input-required").attr("value","New value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="form-submit"]').val("new value");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43319893/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

For be sure to change the right element in you page you should check every attribute you can:

```
if( body.hasClass("page-id-2383") ) {
  $('input[name="form-submit"].input-required').val("New Value");
}
```

This should work.
If it doesn't you can try also .attr("value","New Value") or .prop("value", "New Value")

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you can try to change that value using php `gettext` filter for wordpress.

2) If JS solution is needed, The only correct solution is to select it using parent selector :

```
$(".input-row > .submit-wrap > .input-required").attr("value","New value");
```